# Ant-Contrib propertyregex return all matches by appending chars

Tags: regex, ant, ant-contrib

My ant build can receive any one of the following input (typical classpath);

```
D:\Source\Dir1
D:\Source\Dir1;
D:\Source\Dir1;D:\Source\Dir2
/Source/Dir1
/Source/Dir1:
/Source/Dir1:/Source/Dir2
```

And I would like to transform above entries as follows via RegEx;

```
-ID:\Source\Dir1
-ID:\Source\Dir1
-ID:\Source\Dir1 -ID:\Source\Dir2
-I/Source/Dir1
-I/Source/Dir1
-I/Source/Dir1 -I/Source/Dir2
```

So far I have following in my ANT;

```
<propertyregex property="Example1-Result" input="${example}" regexp="[^${path.separator}^$]+(?:)*" replace="-I\0 " global="true"/>
```

Which generates following :(

```
 -ID:\Source\Dir1 
 -ID:\Source\Dir1 ;
 -ID:\Source\Dir1 ;-ID:\Source\Dir2 
 -I/Source/Dir1 
 -I/Source/Dir1 :
 -I/Source/Dir1 :-I/Source/Dir2
```

Just want to get rid of the **;** and **:** from the the result.

Comment: Why not just run it through propertyregex a second time to get rid of those two characters? Are you expecting them to appear elsewhere in the data?

Comment: No but what would be the second expression? Just want to remove ; and :

Comment: Created a post showing that approach. Notice how it uses override to re-use the same property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in two passes to make this clearer. The first statement is yours:

```
<propertyregex property="Example1-Result" input="${example}" 
            regexp="[^${path.separator}^$]+(?:)*" replace="-I\0 " global="true"/>
```

The second is a simple search and replace to remove any colons or semi-colons that remain:

```
<propertyregex property="Example1-Result" input="${Example1-Result}" 
                    regexp="[:;]" replace=" " global="true" override="true"/>
```

This approach assumes that there aren't semicolons or colons in normal file names, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: Thanks...that's correct. I have also got another solution which was very simple. See below;
`<propertyregex property="Example1-Result" input="${example}" 
            regexp="\${path.separator}" replace=" -I" global="true"/>
<property name="Example1-Result.Final" value="-I${Example1-Result}" />`
First statement will replace `; and :` to ` -I` and second statement simply adds `-I` for the first entry in classpath